# Laravel - How to prevent row getting deleted when there is dependent field

Tags: laravel

I am a laravel beginner. In my laravel CRUD project, I have these migration table

GroupTable

```
class Group extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('group', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('group_code');
            $table->string('group_desc');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

CategoryTable

```
class Category extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('category_code');
            $table->string('category_desc');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

ItemTable

```
class Item extends Migration
{
   /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
     public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('item', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->bigIncrements('id');
           $table->string('item_code');
           $table->string('item_desc');
           $table->string('item_picture');
           $table->string('item_cost');
           $table->string('item_price');
           $table->string('group_desc');
           $table->string('category_desc');
           $table->timestamps();
       });

      
   }
```

The group_desc and category_desc from ItemTable are foreign key from GroupTable and CategoryTable.

GroupController

```
 public function destroy($id)
    {
        Group::find($id)->delete();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Group deleted successfully.']);
    }
```

CategoryController

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        Category::find($id)->delete();
     
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Category deleted successfully.']);
    }
```

This is the ajax delete function in my view of group

```
  //Delete
   $('body').on('click', '.deleteRecord', function () {
     
     var id = $(this).data("id");
     if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete? "))
   
    {
      $.ajax({
         type: "DELETE",
         url: "{{ url('group/delete') }}" + '/' + id,
         success: function (data) {
             table.draw();
         },
         error: function (data) {
             console.log('Error:', data);
         }
     });
    }
 });
```

Before user want to delete the row on GroupTable or CategoryTable, how to display a message shows that the row are not allow to delete if ItemTable have data from GroupTable or CategoryTable?

Comment: You could add a "confirm" section to your `destroy` method that returns the message and requires a resubmission with "confirm" in it to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the foreign key and if it is not a 'cascade' delete, then laravel won't allow you to delete the row when If the same Id used somewhere. for example,

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade'); //inside item table. (CASCADE delete).


$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');// non-cascade
```

assume, If you are using cascade delete, and you are trying to delete the category which is used in the item table, this will delete the category and related item lists in item table.

If you are using non-cascade method, It won't allow you to delete the category when it is used in item table.

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `item` add constraint `item_category_desc_foreign` foreign key (`category_desc`) references `category` (`category_desc`))


Hi, I faced this error when I tried to migrate again to the database. Isit the 'category_desc which I assigned as a string type cannot be use as a foreign key?

Comment: Hi Jack, Actually you have to Do $table->engine = “InnoDB”; in your migration file, because in MySQL default is MyISAM hence this line is a must. and make sure that, item table foreign key and category table 'id' value both are same value. for example in item table's foreign key(category_id) and category table primary key which is autoincrement id both are integer(20) or same. hope it works.

Comment: Hi Arul, so does it work if use on string field as example item table's foreign key(category_desc) and category table (category_desc)

Comment: No, you should use only integer values. If it is a primary key then you can use bigIncrements() otherwise you have to use integer() or bigInteger(). you should use any of these. the foreign key is mainly used for eloquent relationships. this is a really very good feature from laravel. try to explore those concepts

Answer (score 0):

If you follow Laravel's convention, things will be a lot easier to do. Might be longer at first but it gets better

(I am assuming you are using Laravel 8)

1: Table names are usually in plural forms, so your tables should be `groups`, `categories` and `items`

2: Next is to properly define foreign keys for `groups` and `categories` tables in `items` table like this

```
Schema::create('item', function (Blueprint $table) {
   //...
   $table->foreignId('group_id')->constrained();
   $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained();
   //...
});
```

3: Define the respective relations in the 3 models

Group Model

```
namespace App\Models;
class Group extends Model
{
  //...
  public function items(){
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
  }
  //...
}
```

Category model

```
namespace App\Models;
class Category extends Model
{
  //...
  public function items(){
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
  }
  //...
}
```

Item Model

```
namespace App\Models;
class Item extends Model
{
  //...
  public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
  
  public function group(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
  }
  //...
}
```

All the above, while kind of long, will make your work easier later.

From here you can implement the following

GroupController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $group = Group::withCount('items')
      ->find($id);
     
    if($group->items_count < 1){
      $group->delete()
      return response()->json(['success'=>'Group deleted successfully.']);
    }
      
    return response()->json(['fail'=> 'Group has items, cannot be deleted.' ]);
}
```

CategoryController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $category = Category::withCount('items')
      ->find($id);
     
    if($category->items_count < 1){
      $category->delete()
      return response()->json(['success'=>'Category deleted successfully.']);
    }
      
    return response()->json(['fail'=> 'Category has items, cannot be deleted.' ]);
}
```